# What redirect uri should I use on a local system?

Tags: google-oauth

I am using Google Oauth API to get calendar information to my raspberry pi. The raspberry has a local webserver running, only accessible from my local network. What redirect uri should I use to get the authorization response to work?

If I run the Python script on my computer I could obviously use localhost. That did not work if connecting to my Raspberry (via http) and try to get access, then I get redirected to localhost (obviously) instead of 192.168.1.20 or whatever IP my raspberry currently has.

How could I solve this?

Comment: just use a Client ID for native application leave the redirect Uri set to urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

- You can use `http:/192.168.1.20/...` as the redirect URI . That's assuming that your Raspberry PI's address does not change.
- Another option is to create a credential for an *installed application* in the Cloud Console. With this you can use the redirect URI `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`. Instead of redirecting you, this URI will make Google display a code that you must manually provide to your Raspberry Pi application. Typically you would provide a text in your web interface where the user can copy/paste the code. [You can find more info about installed applications and OAuth here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp).

Comment: I guess that th installed application solution is the way to go. The only thing disturbing me is that you must manually copy and paste it.