# Why do I get "redirect_uri_missmatch"?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I am trying to authorize to [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) using [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2). I guess that there is something wrong with my request because I get a `redirect_uri mismatch` error.

I am using the redirect uri `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` and this is a native application from my project in  [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0).

The login page redirects the user to Googles authorization page and the /oauth2callback is taking the information from a submitted form with the generated Google code.
The code is

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                               client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                               scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                               redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
                               approval_prompt='force',
                               access_type='offline')

    auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

    return redirect(auth_uri)


@app.route('/oauth2callback', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def oauth2callback():
    code = request.form['code']
    if code:
        # exchange the authorization code for user credentials
        flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID,
                                   CLIENT_SECRET,
                                   scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
                                   redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
        flow.redirect_uri = request.base_url
        try:
            credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
            storage = Storage('credentials.dat')
            storage.put(credentials)

        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning("Unable to get an access token because "+e.message)

    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: redirect uri must match the redirect uri you have set up in developer console.   'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'  is for native client which type did you create?

Comment: I have created a native application, as I said "installed application" which I think is the same thing.

Comment: Sorry my python knowledge is very limited I thought it was simply a web scripting language.  I didn't release that it could be installed.  I have tried retagging your question someone with Python skills should be able to help you.

Comment: I am not shure about what you mean by "installed". The thing is that this is going to be run locally on a computer with a random local ip-adress (192.168.x.x), accessable only from the local network. Therefore I can not use a http://localhost as redirect uri and not a static ip either. I choose this to be an "installed application" because then I can use the urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob redirect uri. 

I don't think that if python could be "installed" or not is relevant for this question but I might be wrong.

Comment: This is like a follow up on my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056545/what-redirect-uri-should-i-use-on-a-local-system

Comment: it "should" work but I have seen that uri:ietf... thing be buggy.   try and give it 127.0.0.1 in the dev console and in your code.  or localhost oh and it may need a file   http://127.0.0.1/Whatever.php (python version :)

Comment: Since you are actually running as a web server, using oob mode probably won't work.

Comment: So, how should I solve this?